# DRCP: link V$CPOOL_CONN_INFO with process or session

Tags: php, oracle

We are using DRCP on oracle11GR2.
PHP programs are connecting via DRCP mechanism.
Some of them don't use class name (connection classes)
We can see it for example here:

```
    SQL> select cclass_name from SYS.V_$CPOOL_CONN_INFO t
  2  where t.CCLASS_NAME like '%.OCI:SP%';
CCLASS_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HR.OCI:SP:VrTPt6ovb+3gU2c2QwotSD
HR.OCI:SP:VrTUiOwbcWzgU2c2QwrueA
HR.OCI:SP:VrTDd2EXbNrgU2c2QwppDC
HR.OCI:SP:VrStd0RaZqbgU2c2QwrYOB
HR.OCI:SP:VrS7pWwzap/gU2c2Qwoi1B
GUEST.OCI:SP:VrTHg68PbTbgU2c2QwphTC
GUEST.OCI:SP:VrTKGjaBbgbgU2c2QwpPDD
GUEST.OCI:SP:VrTCpw5jbMDgU2c2Qwo9pD
8 rows selected

SQL>
```

I want to know which application is doing that and to avoid this comportement.
So I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to join SYS.V_$CPOOL_CONN_INFO with view like v$session or v$process to know which process is guilty?

2) May I ask php team to force an environment variable in the configuration file to force a default class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PROGRAM and MACHINE columns of V$CPOOL_CONN_INFO are probably what you want to look at.

You can join with V$SESSION on SADDR / SESSION_ADDR

Don't forget to ask the developers to set the tracing attributes like

```
oci_set_action() — Sets the action name
oci_set_module_name() - Sets the module name
oci_set_client_info() - Sets the client information
oci_set_client_identifier() - Sets the client identifier
```

The rationale behind not having a default connection class in php.ini is that this may 'leak' session information between applications that shouldn't be sharing it. If you feel strongly, the place to ask for changes is in the [PHP bug database](https://bugs.php.net/report.php).